# Как передать через AJAX одновременно изображение и несколько переменных?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

тестирую на PHP загружается ли изображение на сервер:

```
<?
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

Если передаю только картинку:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'add_t.php',
    data: ({fd:fd}),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); //выводит массив с данными о файле
    }
});
```

Если несколько переменных:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'add_t.php',
    data: ({fd:fd, name:$('.nme').val()}),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); //выводит что массив пустой
    }
});
```

Получается что изображение тогда не передается, и переменная тоже. Что можно сделать?

Код:

```
<label>фото товара:</label> 
<input type="file" class="form-control ph" style="">
<label>Имя товара:</label> 
<input type="text" class="form-control nme" style="">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setimage() {
    var $input = $(".ph");
    var fd = new FormData;

    fd.append('img', $input.prop('files')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'add_t.php',
            data: ({fd:fd, name:$('.nme').val()}),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-success').click(function(){
        setimage()
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fd.append('img', $input.prop('files')[0]);
fd.append('name', $('.nme').val());
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: fd,
```

Comment: точно.. спасибо)

Comment: сейчас приму ответ.. что-то не пускает)